# For loop confused as to which value to consider

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have this loop here:

```
while(n != 0)
    {
        ld = n % 10;
        System.out.println(ld);

        for ( i=1; i <= ld; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
        }

        System.out.println(f);

        n /= 10;
    }
```

Let us consider a number, say `123`. Now, this loop calculates the factorial of `3` accurately, but when it restarts to calculate the factorial of `2`, the for loop gets confused as to which value to take for the variable `ld`. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Share your output and what you expect the code to do

Comment: Your for loop gets confused? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: Well, I got my answer thank you all!

Comment: Side note: it is not 1985 any more. There is absolutely no good reason to use single characters for variable names. Give variables names that say what they mean. Then: always declare variables to have minimal scope. Meaning: if you had declared "f" within the while loop body ... it would have been much easier to spot for yourself ... that "hey, when is f initialized, and what happens on subsequent runs of the outer loop"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `ld`. You forgot to reset`f` in each iteration.

```
while(n != 0)
{
    ld = n % 10;
    System.out.println(ld);
    f = 1; // reset f
    for ( i=1; i <= ld; i++)
    {
        f = f * i;
    }

    System.out.println(f);

    n /= 10;
}
```

Output :

```
3
6 // factorial of 3
2
2 // factorial of 2
1
1 // factorial of 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `f` once you are done with one number.
Add `f = 1;` when you enter in while loop.

**Solution**

```
      while(n != 0)
        {
            ld = n % 10;
            f = 1;// add this
            System.out.println(ld);

            for (int i=1; i <= ld; i++)
            {
                f = f * i;
            }

            System.out.println(f);

            n /= 10;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most important:

1. Now our loop resets f to 1 every "repeat".

Additional:

1. Added `int i = 1` to for loop.
2. You can use `f *= 1;` instead of `f = f * 1;`
3. Changed n != 0 to n > 0 for more safety .

   while(n > 0)
   {

   ld = n % 10;

   ```
   System.out.println(ld);

   f = 1;   


   for(int i = 1; i <= ld; i++)
   {
       f *= i;
   }

   System.out.println(f);


   n /= 10;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

You may look in to this code,code is ok just need to set the value for f inside the loop for each digit for given number.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    int ld;
        int n=123;

    while(n != 0)
    {
            int f=1;
        ld = n % 10;
        System.out.println(ld);

        for ( int i=1; i <= ld; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
        }

        System.out.println(f);

        n /= 10;
    }
    }
}
```

output are as

```
3
6
2
2
1
1
```